# Im trying to create a button with an data-transition but is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Im trying to create a button with an data-transition but is not working.
 when I click the link `contactInf`, it can not form page `basicInf` switch to page  `contactInf`!

My browser is firefox14.1.

Below is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="basicInf" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
  <a href="#contactInf" data-transition="flip"  data-theme="c" data-  ini="true">contactInf</a>
</div>

<div id="contactInf" data-role="page" data-theme="c">……</div>

</body>
```

Comment: 1) What your have written is neither button nor an anchor. So it will not naturally redirect you anywhere.
2) Its a div, so you need to explicitly specify where you want that div redirect you to. :)

Comment: What doesn't work about your code? I copied/pasted your code and it works just fine, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/MT79M/

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html. Check-out those docs, jQuery Mobile disables transitions when a browser can't handle them or the device-width is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're looking for something like:

HTML

```
<a id="basicInf_link">basic</a>
<a id="contactInf_link">contact</a>

<div id="basicInf" class="page" data-role="page" data-theme="c">……</div>
<div id="contactInf" class="page" data-role="page" data-theme="c">……</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#basicInf_link').click(function () {
  $('.page').hide();
  $('#basicInf').show();
});

$('#contactInf_link').click(function () {
  $('.page').hide();
  $('#contactInf').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, I`m afraid that codes run in the mobile phone will slow.

Comment: This answer is strange, by default, jQuery Mobile will transition between pseudo-pages when you link to them by putting the ID of the page you want to transition-to in the `href` attribute of a link. Also this answer does not refer to `data-transition` so I don't see how it's a good answer. Here is an example of this working with the OPs code: http://jsfiddle.net/MT79M/. I just want to make sure people don't think you need to do this in a jQuery Mobile site, this functionality is baked-in (and the included code is slick)...

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` method:

```
$("#contactInf").click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'yourcontactInfpage.html'
});
```

OR

Change your DIV to

```
<div id="contactInf" data-role="page" data-theme="c" onclick="redirectTocontactInf">……</div>
```

and write this function in your `javascript` file

```
function redirectTocontactInf(){
        window.location.href = 'yourcontactInfpage.html'
}
```

PS : Replace `yourcontactInfpage.html` with the name of the page you want to redirect your user to :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!    But, I`m afraid that codes  run in the mobile phone will not very well.

Comment: @amy whats the problem?
Did you try it yourself?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MT79M/. There is an example of the OPs code working. Your answer seems to have been written without any knowledge of jQuery Mobile, because jQM has the desired functionality baked-in.